# Get Element using elementtree python

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

My XML looks something like: (Sorry if duplicate question, but I'm not very experienced with XML so I have a bit trouble with the terminology

```
<sometags>
    <Value>
        <Scalar unitGlobalDataRef="Unit_0" unit="None" xmlns="xxxxyyyy">20</Scalar> 
    </Value>
</sometags>
```

Using this code:

```
element = ET.parse(fileName)
root = element.getroot()
for subelement in root:
    if (subelement.tag == "{xxyy}Parameter"):
        for value in subelement:
            for subval in value:
                #Here is where it prints
                if (subval.tag == "{xxxxyyyy}Scalar"):
                    print subval.tag
                    print subval.text
                    print subval.tail
                    print subval.attrib
```

prints

```
{xxxxyyyy}Scalar
0


{'unitGlobalDataRef': 'Unit_0', 'unit': 'None'}
```

How can I get the value 20 out from the element?

Comment: What parser created the `subval` variable?

Comment: Edited with more of the code, hope it helps (can't post the whole code / XML without having to censor and rename a lot of stuff)

Comment: I'd expect it to be subval.text: http://ideone.com/1D2zj

Comment: By the way, with lxml you can do `root.findall('.//{xxxxyyyy}Scalar')` for a recursive search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

subval.text should containt the information you're seeking.  Since you're getting a 0, it implies that your iterations may be wrong, and you're getting a different element than you think you are.  This is further reinforced by the fact that your attributes don't match.

Comment: You are correct, somehow I must have failed with the printouts or something. Using if ``subval.text != "0" : print subval.text`` I found the correct values